# How to find polygons within the radius of GEOGRAPHY (point)

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table having all areas with their covered polygons.

```
area_name, polygon
```

Now i want to write a query to fetch all the polygons within 60km radius of specific point(lng/lat)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use `ST_DWITHIN` [function](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#st_dwithin).

```
SELECT 
  area_name, 
  polygon
FROM source AS s
WHERE ST_DWITHIN(s.polygon, ST_GEOGPOINT(lng, lat), 60*1000)
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider below toy example of looking for all zip codes within the 10km from Los Angeles Disneyland Park

```
SELECT point, zipcode, ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(zipcode_geom) zip_geom
FROM `bigquery-public-data.utility_us.zipcode_area`,
UNNEST([ST_GEOGPOINT(-117.9190, 33.8121)]) point
WHERE state_code = 'CA'
AND ST_DWITHIN(ST_GEOGFROMTEXT(zipcode_geom), point, 10000)
```

the output is 36 zip codes like below

[image]

if to visualize this result - you get below

[image]

Comment: Hi Mikhail, I see that you hard coded one lat/lng value. How would you structure the query for a list of values? Say you want to retrieve the zip codes within a 250 kilometer radius of 10 different origin zip codes?